# CakePHP 3, validator: domain translation and placeholders

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

suppose I have this:

```
$validator->add('title', [
    'lengthBetween' => [
        'message'   => 'Must be between %d and %d chars',
        'rule'      => ['lengthBetween', 3, 100]
    ]
])
```

I want to know:

1. how to indicate the domain translation (with CakePHP 2.x, you could use the `$validationDomain` model property);
2. how to use placeholders for validation messages (seems doesn't work with either `%s/%d` or `{0}`).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeholders were removed in 3.x. The reason behind this is that it is now easier to translate messages for validation as they now live in a method instead of a class property.

So the actual way of doing it is:

```
$validator->add('title', [
    'lengthBetween' => [
        'message'   => __('Must be between {0} and {1} chars', 3, 100),
        'rule'      => ['lengthBetween', 3, 100]
    ]
])
```

Comment: Thanks @Josè. So, for the domain, can I use `__d()`?

Comment: Yes you can use `__d('validation', '...')` for using the validation message domain